# PowerShell: Move Wildcard Folder structure files to a destination folder

Tags: windows, directory, wildcard, move

I'm a beginner with PowerShell, so pardon stupid question. On a daily basis I get incoming xml data in a folder on my Win 200 server, e.g. c:\xml-in. 
Some folders match the name pattern dd1-????????-fa???.
Those folders (matching that wildcard mask) are about 30 different folders and I want to move them to a separate folder, e.g. c:\xml-fa\ using one command.

I have searched but the closest solution is 
[Move Wildcard Folder structure files to a destination folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455081/move-wildcard-folder-structure-files-to-a-destination-folder)

The example above does not seem to be from PowerShell.

I have also searched for relevant examples/syntax using the Move-Item Cmdlet.

Can somebody help with other syntax?

best regards